# How to fix image height issue on WebKit when parent is set to inline-flex?

Tags: html, css

I noticed this bug on Firefox and Safari on iOS, but it is also present on Safari on macOS. Affected browsers are all based on WebKit. The package I am using ([react-medium-image-zoom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-medium-image-zoom)) requires a parent with `display: inline-flex` and my design requires that images have `width: 100%`.

**Firefox on macOS (expected)**

[image: Firefox on macOS]

**Safari on macOS (deformed)**

[image: Safari on macOS]

**Please try running the following code snippet on Safari on macOS.**

```css
.container {
  width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
}
.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <div class="flex">
          <img src="https://sunknudsen.com/static/media/privacy-guides/brute-forcing-your-very-own-vanity-onion-address-at-11646mhs/tesla-v100.jpg" width="100%" />
      </div>
      <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `align-items: flex-start;` to your `.flex`:

```css
.container {
  width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
}

.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div class="flex">
      <img src="https://sunknudsen.com/static/media/privacy-guides/brute-forcing-your-very-own-vanity-onion-address-at-11646mhs/tesla-v100.jpg" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```